# What is the pygame window class?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a python library, and I need to check if a parameter is a pygame window so I don't run into errors. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def paramNotTypeException(paramName, typeName):
    return Exception(f"The {paramName} parameter must be of type {typeName}.")

def drawGenome(genome: Genome, window: #whateverthepygamewindowclassis):
    if not isinstance(genome, Genome):
        raise paramNotTypeException("genome", "Genome")

    if not isinstance(window, #what ever the pygame window class is):
        raise paramNotTypeException("window", "Pygame Window")
```

so in draw genome I need to check if the window parameter is a pygame window.
Does anyone no how to do this? If you need more info, just let me know in the comments.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: pygame has no window class. pygame draws the scene on a [pygame.Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object that is associated to the window.

Comment: @Rabbid76 So if I did not isinstance(window, the pygame surface object) that would work?

Comment: Just figured it out. When you call pygame.display.set_mode it returns a Surface object. So if you try my isinstance it will work, you can write an answer just saying that the pygame.Surface is the window object and I can accept that answer as it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame has no window class. Pygame draws the scene on a [pygame.Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object that is associated to the window:

```py
if isinstance(window, pygame.Surface):
```

You can get a reference to the currently set display *Surface* with [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface):

```py
if window == pygame.display.get_surface():
```